# What is the correct dependency rpm for libcurl.so.3

Tags: linux, php, centos, rpm, curl

So I have a failed dependency and I am having trouble downloading the correct rpm. The error is `libcurl.so.3()(64bit) is needed`. I have Centos 6 and I have looking in this site for the correct rpm. The problem though is, and this is another place where linux fails in being intuitive, is that the rpm name is different than the dependency name. So it might be a curl3 rpm or a libcurl3 rpm or I have no idea.

Anyone know which one it is?

Comment: What is it you are trying to install and how are you installing it ?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a `libcurl.so.3` for CentOS 6.

```
yum whatprovides */libcurl.so.*

...

libcurl-7.19.7-26.el6_2.4.x86_64 ...
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
```

The rpm that provides libcurl.so.* is libcurl. Going to a CentOS mirror and looking in `/centos/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/` we see the earliest version of that package is libcurl-7.19.7-16.el6.i686.rpm which contains libcurl.so.4 also.

Comment: how would you apply your answer if already installed and latest version
Nothing to do?  why does the error msg: `Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)` still appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try following whenever you have dependancy issue. ( I assume that you have enabled correct repo)

# yum whatprovides "*/filename"

HTH

Comment: I tried `yum whatprovides "*/libcurl.so.3"` but it returned nothing.

Comment: what is output of yum repolist ?